# How to write a Patch for VyOS kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, c, patch

I am new to VyOS development. I have written a patch which will fetch info from the VyOS kernel module and write it on a netlink socket. But the problem is I am not sure if I should edit the kernel module code directly to call my defined function or I should write the patch. If I have to make a patch file for it then where do I place it in the kernel source code? I have already made a patch file using the diff command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I solved the problem I was facing. Here is conclusions in case any of you gets stuck in same problem.

1. Yes, you can edit the kernel module code in VyOS Development. But this method is not much appreciated.
2. Yes, you can write patch for kernel modules too. and it should be in GIT formate as described in [How to write VyOS Patch](http://vyos.net/wiki/Submit_a_patch). Soon I will update, where to place `.patch` file in VyOS kernel code.

To check the debugging output using `dmesg`,  use `KERN_DEBUG` option. As I am not sure about others.

`printk(KERN_DEBUG "%s: Debuging info \n",  __FUNCTION__);`

Moreover to check modification in VyOS kernel you don't need to make a complete ISO file all the time. You just need to run following commands.

*Note each path is
described everytime from the main iso building directory to avoid path problems.

```
cd build-iso/
sudo make clean-linux-image
sudo make linux-image
```

Then

```
cd buil-iso/pkgs/
```

Here you will find these debian packages.

```
buil-iso/pkgs/linux-image-3.13.11-1-amd64-vyos_999.dev_amd64.deb
buil-iso/pkgs/linux-libc-dev_999.dev_amd64.deb
buil-iso/pkgs/linux-vyatta-kbuild_999.dev_amd64.deb
```

Copy these files to an already installed VyOS Sytem and install them over there.

```
dpkg -i linux-image-3.13.11-1-amd64-vyos_999.dev_amd64.deb
dpkg -i linux-libc-dev_999.dev_amd64.deb
dpkg -i linux-vyatta-kbuild_999.dev_amd64.deb
```

`reboot` the system and check you modifications using `dmesg`.